# Old name of the procedure in sp_helptext

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Some time ago the procedure `ALF_GetPopulationForPolygon_2_old` was created. Then in SSMS, it was renamed `(right mouse button -> rename)` to the procedure `ALF_GetPopulationForPolygon_2_old_FOR_DELETE_20170504`. Renaming passed normally, but as a result, the query:

```
SELECT
    sm.definition
FROM
    sys.objects AS o
        INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS sm
        ON ( 1 = 1 )
           AND ( sm.object_id = o.object_id )
WHERE
    ( 1 = 1 )
    AND ( o.name like 'ALF_GetPopulationForPolygon_2_old_FOR_DELETE_20170504' )
```

And calling the stored procedure:

```
EXEC sp_helpText 'ALF_GetPopulationForPolygon_2_old_FOR_DELETE_20170504'
```

Return the following text:

```
...
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo]. [ALF_GetPopulationForPolygon_2]
...
```

Those show the OLD(!) name of the procedure. Do you have any idea what this is caused, and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't rename your objects for at least two reasons.

If you'd use a T_SQL command instead of GUI (all that you "clicks" in Management Studio produces T-SQL coede behind the scenes), you'd get a warning, the same you can see in BOL article: 
[sp_rename (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351(v=sql.110).aspx)

> CAUTION Changing any part of an object name can break scripts and stored
>   procedures. We recommend you do not use this statement to rename
>   stored procedures, triggers, user-defined functions, or views;
>   instead, drop the object and re-create it with the new name.

And it was the first reason against renaming.
Scrolling the article find the Remarks section:

> Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger will
>   not change the name of the corresponding object name in the definition
>   column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view. Therefore, we recommend
>   that sp_rename not be used to rename these object types. Instead, drop
>   and re-create the object with its new name.

And this was the second.

So when you want to rename your procedure you should script your procedure as CREATE and change the procedure name, doing so you recreate your proc with the new name and then you can drop the old one

Comment: It is unbelievable, that this bug is documented as feature (warning) by Microsoft. Of course that renaming will break dependencies, it is clear. But if I rename object, the corresponding source code of *THIS* object must be updated. I spent several hour on this issue today :(

Comment: I wish the SQL team would add an option in the settings to change the behavior of renaming via object explorer such that it drops and recreates rather than renaming via sp_rename.

Comment: Interestingly, even `sp_refreshsqlmodule` and `sp_recompile` (which normally fix metadata issues like this) do not pick up the altered definition. It's apparently stored only on create and update and no other operation affects it. That `sp_rename` does not is quasi-forgivable if there was a way to refresh the definition without recreating the procedure entirely, but there isn't, and that's a problem (it may be quite complicated if you have to redo permissions as well, for starters).